# spring security session management conflict with tomcat webapp path

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security

I am implementing the web logout process using spring security.
When I ran a web project with IDE (e.g., eclipse) in the development environment, I ran the webapp through the ROOT path, so it was processed normally.

However, when I distributed it to the actual environment, I registered the path to my service because I had to register several services in one Tomcat.

For example... http://localhost:8080/ -> http://localhost:8080/operator

As a result of distributing the webapp as above, two problems appeared.

1. When logging out, move to invalid-session-url.
2. Duplicate session detection, expired-url ignored and moved to invalid-session-url.

The example below is part of my spring security setting xml file.
When distributing to Tomcat, when adding path to the webapp, is there any part that needs to be set up in session-management?
It works normally in the local environment, so I think that's definitely the problem.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.io" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/callApiService" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/loginprocess"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?auth=fail"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customLoginSuccessHandler"
        default-target-url="/"
    />
    
    <security:logout 
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        logout-url="/logout" 
        logout-success-url="/login"
    />

    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login?auth=invalid">
        <security:concurrency-control 
            max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"
            expired-url="/login?auth=expired"
        />
    </security:session-management>
     
</security:http>
```

Comment: Can you please share you stacktrace if there is any?
Or screenshot the the behavior?

Comment: Show your requests and responses with headers. For example a screeshot of your dev tool in your browser (F12).